# Rails choosing wrong route when looping through a nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got two resources, `Clients` and `Projects`.

In `routes.rb`:

```
resources :clients do
  resources :projects
end
```

`rake routes` gives me this the route prefix `client_project` for the `projects#show` action

In my view, I call:

```
<% @client.projects.each do |project| %>
  <%= link_to project.name, project %>
<% end %>
```

and Rails keeps throwing an error: `undefined method project_path`, which tells me for some reason the view is trying to call `project_path` and not `client_project_path`. I've tried rebooting my server (even rebooting my computer), and can't seem to find why it won't call the route properly. I recently refactored my routes (which caused this break). Am I missing something here? This exact pattern works in every other model in my app, only the refactored route doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never had success getting nested routes to work by simply passing the object in question as the url parameter of `link_to`...  Plus (and maybe it's just me) I like my templates to be a bit more "explicit" than that.

A couple things you could do:

`<%= link_to project.name, url_for([@client, project]) %>`

or

`<%= link_to project.name, client_project_path(@client, project) %>`

Comment: This works great. I had refactored from a shallow resource, which would explain the issue. How would I handle the `edit_client_project_path` url? Using `edit_client_project_path(screen)` throws an error of "missing required keys: [:id]"

Comment: Try `url_for([:edit, @client, project])` or `edit_client_project_path(@client, project)`

Answer (score 0):

If projects is a nested route it won't have a project_path route unless you explicitly define one.  The Project URLs require a Client.  Check this out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources